# Create a responsive div with two background colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a div with 2 background colors. Both colors have a sharp edge and that edge must connect the top right corner(please see the html output to understand what I mean).
The DIV must be responsive.

I tried to do it using two DIV elements. But this approach is not responsive as I had to use  fixed height for parent and fixed width for  child div (50px).

Perfect solution for my question would be to use only one DIV and create the color effect using linear-gradient function.

Other solution would be somehow set the child div's width to parent's height dynamically.

There can be other solutions also. I will be grateful for any help.

```css
.parent {
    width: 70%;
    height:50px;
   background-color: black;
 }

 .child {
   width:50px;
   height: 100%;
   float:right;
   background: linear-gradient(135deg, #000000 50%, red 50%);
 }
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on which browsers you want to support. If you only want to support the most bleeding-edge browsers, you can simply use an absolutely positioned pseudo-element whose [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) is set to 1 (which creates a square), and it will be responsive.

In the example below, I have added `resize: both` to the parent element, so you can resize it as you wish to test the responsiveness:

```css
.parent {
  width: 70%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  
  /* For demonstration purposes only */
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, red 50%);
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
</div>
```